Proof General tell Coq where a physical path is
Here is the first few lines of Auto.v in Software Foundations Volume 1.
(** * Auto: More Automation *)                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                             
Set Warnings "-notation-overridden,-parsing,-deprecated-hint-without-locality".                                                                                                              
From Coq Require Import Lia.
From LF Require Import Maps.
From LF Require Import Imp.

If you try to check the file in Proof General you get the following error.
Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path Maps with prefix LF.

This isn't a problem when using the Makefile to build the project, since we pass in an argument to coq_makefile that tells it that LF is the current directory (I think).
COQMFFLAGS := -Q . LF  

ALLVFILES := Preface.v Basics.v Induction.v Lists.v Poly.v Tactics.v Logic.v IndProp.v Maps.v ProofObjects.v IndPrinciples.v Rel.v Imp.v ImpParser.v ImpCEvalFun.v Extraction.v Auto.v AltAuto.v Postscript.v Bib.v  PrefaceTest.v  BasicsTest.v  InductionTest.v  ListsTest.v  PolyTest.v  TacticsTest.v  LogicTest.v  IndPropTest.v  MapsTest.v  ProofObjectsTest.v  IndPrinciplesTest.v  RelTest.v  ImpTest.v  ImpParserTest.v  ImpCEvalFunTest.v  ExtractionTest.v  AutoTest.v  AltAutoTest.v  PostscriptTest.v  BibTest.v

build: Makefile.coq
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.coq

clean::
        if [ -e Makefile.coq ]; then $(MAKE) -f Makefile.coq cleanall; fi
    $(RM) $(wildcard Makefile.coq Makefile.coq.conf) imp.ml imp.mli imp1.ml imp1.mli imp2.ml imp2.mli

Makefile.coq:
        coq_makefile $(COQMFFLAGS) -o Makefile.coq $(ALLVFILES)

-include Makefile.coq

.PHONY: build clean                     

This file also doesn't contain exercises, it's automation for checking exercises.
However, I'd still like to be able to inspect it using Proof General.
Is there a way to configure Proof General to tell Coq where to find the LF files?
I tried to trick Coq by running $ ln -s . LF to create a directory ./LF that's just a symlink to the root of the Software Foundations book, but that didn't work. Now I'm out of ideas.

How ProofGeneral knows the options to pass to coqtop?
In principle (last time I checked) the LF directory (where Auto.v is located) should have a file called _CoqProject containing -Q . LF. ProofGeneral reads this file when starting coq to elaborate the options.
You can check if this option is actually set by checking the *Messages* buffer, which should contain something like::
Coq project file detected: /.../sfdev/lf/_CoqProject. [3 times]
Starting: coqtop -topfile /.../sfdev/lf/Auto.v -emacs -Q /.../sfdev/lf LF

How to compile the files?
The message you get says that coq does not find the file Maps.vo. which may mean that the option above is correctly set but that this file does not exist because the file Maps.v is not yet compiled. In this case:

either first compile with make then the require should work
or set the option in the mennu Coq -> Auto Compilation -> Compile Before Require (or programmatically with (setq coq-compile-before-require t)) and the compilation should be done by PG itslef.

